# Options to build a production server as a solo python developer?

Tags: python, servers

I'm new to DevOps and overwhelmed with all the options.

I write python web applications as a solo developer, on my local machine. I have a "staging" server and I have multiple websites under different subdomains (eg. myapp.staging.mywebsite.dev). I use git on my local machine and use branches to create multiple versions of my apps and then I use git to push my code to this server so I can see how it looks on the web.

When I'm happy with my web app I want to be able to deploy it to a separate production server, so I can get real users using my apps. I could just use git to push my code to a new server but are there any other options that will help me create a live site?

Comment: https://fly.io/docs/django/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

One option that you could consider is using a continuous deployment tool like Jenkins, Travis CI, or GitLab CI. These tools can automatically deploy your code to a production server whenever you push your code to a certain branch in your git repository. This can save you the time and effort of manually deploying your code to your production server every time you make a change.

Another option is to use a service like Heroku, which makes it easy to deploy and manage your web applications. With Heroku, you can simply push your code to a git repository, and Heroku will automatically build and deploy your application.

Ultimately, the best option will depend on your specific needs and preferences, so it may be worth experimenting with different approaches to see what works best for you.